# How to concat several collections of Observables nested in another Observable

Tags: angular, merge, rxjs, observable, concatenation

I'm new to RxJs and I am struggling with a complex scenario for an Angular app where I have observables nested in other observables (simplified hereafter).

To be concise, I have:

- An *Observable* that returns a stream with a collection of objects *SearchActivity* => `Observable<SearchActivity[]>`
- Each *SearchActivity* object have an Observable property 'results$' => `BehaviorSubject<SearchActivityResult[]>`

I try to extract all the results from inside all the activities to one single Observable.
So, from the following example (this is not code, but an idea of the data structure):

```
Observable<SearchActivity[]> => [
 {id: 1, results$: Observable<SearchActivityResult[]> => [1, 2]},
 {id: 2, results$: Observable<SearchActivityResult[]> => [3, 4, 5]} 
 {id: 3, results$: Observable<SearchActivityResult[]> => [6]} 
]
```

I would like to extract the result to obtain:

```
Observable<SearchActivityResult[]> => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (Edit: the order is not important)
```

How can this could be achieved using RxJs?

So far I got something like:

```
// This is not working properly
this.allResults$ = this.displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => {
    return concat(...activities?.map(activity => activity.results$ || of([])));
  })
);
```

But it doesn't seems to work as expected.

I have prepared a [StackBiltz with a more complex scenario here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-shqx1c?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Update 2021-02-23**

I created a new [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66317277-j2rdxv?file=src/app/app.component.html) where you can interact with the results by clicking on it. The goal is to get a summary of all results for each database (the table at the bottom on the page) and display the amount of positive/negative results across all the search criterions.

**TL;DR => Solution**

I have just created a **new [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ghvq1) with less complexity** in order to isolate the problem. I have included the suggestions made by `Mrk Sef` and it's working.
I have some other errors with the flat operator and a weird circular reference to json but it is more likely cause by the StackBlitz simulator.

Comment: In your result: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` - is order important?

Comment: Not at all, I just need all the results in a single stream

Comment: Is this the expected behavior? : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-acoqa7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Nop, it only get the last observable of results (2 results) in your exemple. It should have all.

Comment: I'd say it would be great if you could simply the StackBlitz app in order to only highlight what's wrong without other details.

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried to simplify it as much as possible. I need this level of complexity to properly expose the problem. But I can add more comments to explain it a bit further if you want. Just tell me how I can help you.

Comment: In your stackblitz it seems you are using `concat` function in line but you are importing the `concat` **operator**  and not the **concat** function (i.e. `import { concat } from "rxjs/operators"` rather than `import { concat } from "rxjs"`). This causes an error which you can see in the console. But then, if you change to the `function`, than a series of type errors arise. Still I think you should put some attention to this piece.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was from previous tests, I now use the merge operator but thx for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, but you need a final step to reduce your stream back into a value for you.

What you've written:

```js
this.allResults$ = this.displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => 
    concat(...activities?.map(
      activity => activity?.results$ || of([])
    ))
  )
);
```

has one emission per entry in `activities`, but you don't want a series of emissions, you'd like an array merging/flattening the results.

You might try something like:

```js
this.allResults$ = this.displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => 
    merge(...activities?.map(
      activity => activity?.results$ || of([])
    ))
  ),
  toArray(),
  map(res => res.flat())
);
```

or

```js
this.allResults$ = this.displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => 
    merge(...activities?.map(
      activity => activity?.results$ || of([])
    ))
  ),
  reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc,...curr], [])
);
```

---

## Update:

You can run this minimal example:

```js
const displayedActivities$ = of([
  {results$: of([1,2,3])},
  {results$: of([10,20,30])},
  {something: "else"},
  {results$: of([100,200,300])}
]);

const allResults$ = displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => 
    merge(...activities.filter(
      activity => activity?.results$ != null
    ).map(
      activity => activity.results$
    ))
  ),
  reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc,...curr], [])
).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### The output:

```js
[1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300]
```

## Update # 2

This is how you might handle changing the property result$ observables to long-lived observables. It's much the same as the `toArray()`, `Array.flat()` above, only now it uses `combineLatest`

This is code that should run. It will keep the most recent emission from each observable as part of the final combined output:

#### Mocking the Settup

Create `displayedActivities$` that emits an array of objects, each with a property `result$` that emits some number of times (3, in this case) before completing.

```js
/****
 * Pipeable Operator:
 * Takes arrays emitted by the source and spaces out their
 * values by the given interval time in milliseconds
 ****/
function intervalArray<T>(intervalTime = 1000): OperatorFunction<T[], T> {
  return pipe(
    concatMap((v: T[]) =>
      concat(
        ...v.map((value: T) =>
          EMPTY.pipe(
            delay(intervalTime),
            startWith(value)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
}

const displayedActivities$ = of([
  { results$: 
    of([
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]
    ]).pipe(intervalArray(250))
  },
  { results$: 
    of([
      [10,20,30],
      [40,50,60],
      [70,80,90]
    ]).pipe(intervalArray(300))
  },
  { something: "else" },
  { results$: 
    of([
      [100,200,300],
      [400,500,600],
      [700,800,900]
    ]).pipe(intervalArray(350))
  }
]);
```

#### Combining for allResults$

```js
const allResults$ = displayedActivities$.pipe(
  mergeMap(activities => 
    combineLatest(...activities.filter(
      activity => activity?.results$ != null
    ).map(
      activity => activity.results$.pipe(startWith([]))
    ))
  ),
  map(latest => latest.flat())
).subscribe(console.log);
```

#### The output:

```js
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,10,20,30]
[1,2,3,10,20,30,100,200,300]
[4,5,6,10,20,30,100,200,300]
[4,5,6,40,50,60,100,200,300]
[4,5,6,40,50,60,400,500,600]
[7,8,9,40,50,60,400,500,600]
[7,8,9,70,80,90,400,500,600]
[7,8,9,70,80,90,700,800,900]
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work, the reducer is not rxjs in your example so you cannot call it after a coma and the merge operator (javascript too).

Comment: Yeah, they're meant to be operators composed by RxJS's pipe. I fixed it.

Comment: I've tried that as well but for some reason it doesn't work.
Without the reduce I got the results[] from the last activity.
And with the reduce I got a null

Comment: I've included some working code that you can run/rinker with. There are any number of reasons you're getting a null, I'll leave the debugging to you. :)

Comment: I still get a null, I think it is because reduce only emit when all the observables are completed. Which is not my case. The streams are open till the angular component is destroyed

Comment: How are you getting a null? Reduce should emit nothing in that case. I'll leave the bug-hunting to you, but I've updated my answer to be able to deal with long-lived observables.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've created a new Stackbiltz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ghvq1) where I have isolated the problem. But I cannot use the flat operator in the simulator (I've tried to change the compile option but without success) so I use 'concat' instead. I also have an annoying error 'circular structure to json' in the console (but I don't understand why).

Comment: I think you've yet to describe your problem very well. I can't read your mind ;) -> looks like your code is running to me!

Comment: Your solution is fully working! I was just wondering why I still got an error with flat and json but it is not important. You have successfully solve my problem!. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to map the observables from the array using `Array#map` and pass it through a `forkJoin` to have parallel requests. Which could be mapped from the source observable using a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap`.

Try the following

```js
Observable<SearchActivity[]>.pipe(
  switchMap((data: any) => 
    forkJoin(data.map(item => 
      item.results$
    ))
  )
).subscribe({
  next: value => {
    console.log(value);
  },
  error: error => {
    // handle error
  }
});
```

Note:

1. `Observable<SearchActivity[]>` here is a placeholder. Replace it with the actual source observable variable.
2. `forkJoin` will emit only when all the source observables complete. If you wish to a stream of data replace it either with `combineLatest` or `zip`.

Comment: Thx, in my case I would rather use the combineLatest operator as the stream will continue to emit (that the purpose of all this stuff). Your solution returns me Observable<SearchActivity[][]>. I need to merge all the results

Comment: @Fab: You could flatten the array of array for one level using [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and RxJS `map`.

Comment: Ok I added a flat after the map but I had to add a casting to SearchArctivity[] or I got a type error. Now I can see a result but still not what I expect. Something like [[{activity1, activity2}],[{activity3}]] instead of [{activity1, activity2}, {activity3}]

Comment: Are you sure the array is flattened? Try flattening to one more level.

Comment: Ok, my bad, the casting was useless. I've just copy your switchmap with (data: any)... :D Still testing... Let you know Thx

Comment: Ok so I got a collection if Observable<SearchActivities[]> which I cannot flatten. I should be able to combine all these Observable into one with a big collection of all the SearchActivities

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work for you:

```js
this.allResults$ = this.displayedActivities$.pipe(
  switchMap(activities => 
    merge(...activities.map(a => a.results$))
  ),                                         
  mergeMap(resultsArray => from(resultsArray)),
  scan((acc, cur) => ([...acc, cur]), [])
);
```

Here's the flow:

- Use [`merge`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge) to create a single observable that emits whenever any of the `activities.results$` emit
- Use [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) / [`from()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) to emit array elements individually
- Use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to put all emissions into a single array

The function inside of `scan` is likely too simplistic as it is simply combining ALL emissions into an array with no accounting for multiple emissions that represent the same result.  I see you have an `id` on the returned `SearchActivityResult` items, so maybe can build a more sophisticated handler function inside of scan that takes that into account.

But hopefully this gets you started.

Here is a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66317277?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanx, this is a promising output. But the scan function is a problem because it adds all the streams results to the same array. Of course, we could modify its function to manage this array but I think it would be more correct to play with an operator such as combineLatest or something to publish the last combination of all the observables. What do you think?

Comment: I have updated my original question with a new StackBlitz so you will understand what I need.